# Display post_meta-by_key on product catalogue

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta

I'm trying to display a custom field in my woocommerce bookshop catalogue.  I have added the field "**author**" and I want to display it after the product title, and before the price.

http://www.modjajibooks.co.za/titles/

I think I've worked out that the place I need to display the author name is ***woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item***,  and I think I need to use this:

`echo get_post_meta_by_key( 'author' );`

But I'm not sure how to put it all together in my child theme's **functions.php**.  This is as far as I got, but I am in need of help.

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_author' );
   function display_author() { 
      echo get_post_meta_by_key( 'author' );
   }
```

I'm getting an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post_meta_by_key()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `get_post_meta_by_key()` isn't a WordPress function.

What you're likely looking for is [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_author' );

function display_author() { 
  global $post;
  echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'author', true );
}
```

Not tested, because I don't have a WooCommerce install handy (and WooCommerce specifics are off-topic here anyway) but this is pretty standard so it should just work for you.

The `true` as the third parameter is so that `get_post_meta()` returns a string, ready to echo directly out. Without `true`, it will return an array instead ([see the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) for further info).